# Is every one-form satisfying these equations closed and co-closed?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, harmonic-functions

Let $\mathbb{D}^2$ be the closed $2$-dimensional unit disk, ebdowed with the Euclidean metric.

Let $\sigma \in \Omega^1(\mathbb{D}^2)$ be a smooth one-form satisfying $d\sigma=\text{const}\cdot dx \wedge dy,\delta \sigma=\text{const}$. ($\delta \sigma=\text{const}$ is equivalent to $d\star \sigma=\text{const} \cdot (dx \wedge dy)$ where $\star$ is the Hodge start operator w.r.t the Euclidean metric.)

In other words, I assume that $\delta \sigma$ is a constant function, and $d\sigma$ is a constant multiple of the standard volume form on $\mathbb{D}^2$.

> Is it true that $d\sigma=0,\delta \sigma=0$?

Comment: Can't you just set up that a generic $1$-form has the form $\sigma=f(x,y)dx+g(x,y)dy$ and the you get two differential equations for $f$ and $g$? There should be nontrivial solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma=f(x,y)dx+g(x,y)dy$ be a generic $1$-form. Then $$d\sigma=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dx\wedge dy + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}dx\wedge dy$$ and $$\delta \sigma = d*\sigma = d(-g(x,y)dx+f(x,y)dy)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}dx\wedge dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx\wedge dy$$

Picking for example $f(x,y)=g(x,y)=x$ gives $d\sigma=dx\wedge dy$ and $\delta \sigma= dx\wedge dy$.

In general $2$ differential equations on two functions of two variables still leave you a lot of wiggle room.